# How to remove from all routes the debug banner (FLUTTER)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, banner

I wonder if exists a way to hide the default banner from all the routes and future ones.

I know there is a way to hide to debug banner of every screen (**debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false**) but that's not what I'd like to do.

I tink that comparing with AStudio for Android native apps would be useful as I want to achieve the same goal.

In AStudio, a similar situation happens with the status bar. Though I can remove it from any single activity (same as screen / route in Flutter), by using the command (getSupportActionBar().hide();), I also can remove it from all activities in the project by typing into the res/values/styles.xml -> .

As I've already said, I 'd like to achieve the same goal with Flutter.

Any help would be appreciated !!

I can hide the debug banner from a sigle route by typing **debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false** but I'd like to remove it from all the routes in the project and oviously the future route I can implement,

Comment: put `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` in MaterialApp that removes all debug banner in it's routes

Comment: Read my question as I already use this.